# Searching a specific folder isn't limited to that folder

Tags: google-drive-api

I'm attempting to use children->listChildren with a folder id and a search parameter, the code looks like this

```
$parameters['q'] = "title = 'Folder Title'";
$children = $dlist->children->listChildren($export_dir, $parameters);
```

Where $export_dir is the id of a folder.  In this case, if I have trashed the folder called 'Folder Title' my search will find it in the Trash folder, NOT the specified folder id.  I was expecting that a trashed folder would not appear in the search results because I specified a different folder to search.  Am I assuming incorrectly or should I be filing a bug report?

Comment: Can you check the metadata for the trashed "Folder Title" and confirm that `$export_dir` is not in the folder's `parents` collection?

Comment: The file layout is /root/A shared dir/Folder Title/arbitrary folder/some file.  I am trashing the folder called Folder Title using Finder on Mac as that's what Google Drive has built there so that the shared 'A shared dir' is then empty.

I can confirm that the parent ID of 'Folder Title' is that of the 'A shared dir' and not the trash dir, which doesn't appear to have an ID.

Comment: The "explicitelyTrashed" flag is set to TRUE however.

Comment: You can set your query parameter as `$parameters['q'] = "title = 'Folder Title' AND trashed = false"` which should strip out files that are in the trash.

Answer (score 1):

When listing files, folder and/or parents, trashed files/folders will be part of the returned collection by default.

To prevent this behavior, use the `q="trashed = false"` query parameter to let the API knows that you are requesting untrashed files/folders. From your code snippet:

```
$parameters['q'] = "title = 'Folder Title' AND trashed = false";
$children = $dlist->children->listChildren($export_dir, $parameters);
```